PyTorch Dropout Behavior - Same Seed Different Dropout Percentage
After setting manual seed in PyTorch, if we apply dropouts in two scenarios on the same layers:

Scenario 1: 10% dropout on linear layer 6 with seed 2024
Scenario 2: 20% dropout on the same linear layer 6 with the same seed 2024

Will this always mean (deterministically) that in Scenario 2, the exact same neurons get dropped out as in Scenario 1 (for the 10%) + some additional neurons (for the remaining 10%)?
Or, does Scenario 2 randomly drop out neurons that may or may not be a part of the original 10% from Scenario 1?

This isn't guaranteed (i.e. there's no explicit guarantee in the documentation). It may actually be true depending on the implementation (from inspection, it appears to be true for the native CPU implementation). Since a naive dropout is easy enough to implement, if you want to rely on this behavior it may be worth writing your own dropout layer.
